# Prove ABA' is singular.

Tags: linear-algebra

A is MxN matrix.

B is NxN matrix.

If N smaller than M

Prove ABA' is singular.(A' is transpose of A)

I don't know how to do.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: A matrix is singular if and only if it is not invertible. Since $N<M$, what can we say about the dimensions of $ABA'$?

Comment: Isn't dimensions of ABA' M^2?

Comment: Yes, and $B$ is $N^2$. Now what does that tell you about whether the columns of $ABA'$ could be linearly independent?

Comment: I actually do not have ideas of relation between B and ABA'.